# How to prevent other show entries to work when I select only one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I assumed that I have 3 show entries on my page. My problem is when I select one from the three. It's all work at the same time. What I want is only the input I select will be work. How can I make it reusable? I will use it on my project. Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/62ujm7Lk/8/

```
  pagination : function(activePage) {
    this.currentPage = activePage;
    this.startIndex = (this.currentPage * this.show_entries) - 
    this.show_entries;
    this.endIndex = parseInt(this.startIndex) + 
    parseInt(this.show_entries);
  },
  showEntries: function(value) {
    this.endIndex = value ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the 'Show X entries' dropdowns in your code. If that is the case, your issue is that you are using the same variable as the 'v-model' for all of them, when one of them gets updated the change gets reflected on all three. You need to use different variables for each if you wish them to be independent.

Comment: If I use different variables, I will also create another two methods for the 2 inputs? I want to make reusable show entries. Is this possible? I think it is redundant to make another method for the other inputs

Comment: No need to make additional methods, just change the variable name in the call to the methods like `@change="showEntries(new_variable_name)"`